# Brunch expose NODE_ENV or environment variable to javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, environment-variables, brunch

I am writing an npm script that will execute a brunch build. I want to pass along an environment variable so that the app will know which set of URLs to use by default for this build (the set of URLs will be changeable at user request from UI). Here's my npm scripts setup so far (I'm on Windows):

```
"scripts": {
  "build:localhost": "SET NODE_ENV=localhost && brunch build",
  "build:develop": "SET NODE_ENV=develop && brunch build",
  "build:production": "SET NODE_ENV=production && brunch build"
}
```

If I `npm run build:localhost` and `console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);` in my brunch-config.js, I get `localhost` as I would expect. But the same `console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);` in one of my javascript files being compiled returns `development`. That's not what I expect - I want it to be `localhost`.

How do I pass the `NODE_ENV` variable that I have set through to my javascript code? More generally, how could I supply a variable to my javascript code from brunch? The `--env` flag for the `brunch` command seems to just be about which setup is used in the [`overrides`](http://brunch.io/docs/config#-overrides-) block of the brunch config.

UPDATE

I was able to do this with [jsenv-brunch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsenv-brunch), found thanks to [this suggestion](https://github.com/brunch/brunch/issues/332#issuecomment-259208302) from @migore, but I wonder if NODE_ENV is supposed to behave the way I've described it is by default, and why if so.